# Is there a way to use react-redux dispatch inside the loader function of react-router-dom?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-router-dom

I am using `react-router-dom@6.8.1` along with `redux-toolkit`. I have a typical scenario where I'm making a backend call to fetch data (this is happening inside a loader function offered by RRD).

Once I fetch the data, I need to update the redux state inside the loader function. (This way, I can avoid another `useEffect` inside my function component). Here is a code snippet to give you a better understanding.

```
const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    errorElement: <Error />,
    children: [
      {
        index: true,
        element: <Home />,
        loader: async () => {
          try {
            const response = await axios({
              method: "get",
              url: "some URL here",
            });
            // State update should happen here using dispatch. **********
            return response;
          } catch (e: any) {
            throw json(
              { message: "Error occured while fetching data" },
              { status: e.status }
            );
          }
        },
      },
    ],
  },
]);
```

Since we cannot use `useDispatch` outside of the React function components or custom hooks, I am wondering if there is any way to achieve this.
I am glad to provide any more details like package.json etc, upon requirement.

Comment: Is it possible to use rtk query hooks directly inside the loader ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do that by wrapping the rendering of your routes inside a component. For example, something like so in `index.js`:

```
function Index() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const router = createBrowserRouter([
    {
      path: "/",
      errorElement: <Error />,
      children: [
        {
          index: true,
          element: <Home />,
          loader: async () => {
            try {
              const response = await axios({
                method: "get",
                url: "some URL here",
              });
              dispatch({ type: "Something" });
              return response;
            } catch (e: any) {
              throw json({ message: "Error occured while fetching data" }, { status: e.status });
            }
          },
        },
      ],
    },
  ]);
  return <RouterProvider router={router} />;
}

// As of React 18
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Index />
  </Provider>
);
```

If you want to pass `dispatch` as a parameter to a loader in a different file, you could use a function that returns the loader that React Router Dom expects, like so, for example:

```
const loadereGetter = (dispatch) => async () => {
  try {
    const response = await axios({
      method: "get",
      url: "some URL here",
    });
    dispatch({ type: "Something" });
    return response;
  } catch (e: any) {
    throw json({ message: "Error occured while fetching data" }, { status: e.status });
  }
};
```

```
function Index() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const router = createBrowserRouter([
    {
      path: "/",
      errorElement: <Error />,
      children: [
        {
          index: true,
          element: <Home />,
          loader: loaderGetter(dispatch),
        },
      ],
    },
  ]);
  return <RouterProvider router={router} />;
}

// As of React 18
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Index />
  </Provider>
);
```

Answer (score 10):

If you don't want to render a parent/wrapper component that can use the `useDispatch` hook and pass `dispatch` down as an argument you can instead import the instantiated `store` object and [dispatch](https://redux.js.org/api/store#dispatchaction) actions directly to the store.

Example:

```js
import { json } from 'react-router-dom';
import { store } from '../path/to/store';

export const homeLoader async () => {
  try {
    const response = await axios({
      method: "get",
      url: "some URL here",
    });

    // State update should happen here using dispatch.
    store.dispatch(stateUpdateAction(/* payload */));

    return response;
  } catch (e: any) {
    throw json(
      { message: "Error occured while fetching data" },
      { status: e.status }
    );
  }
}
```

```
const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    errorElement: <Error />,
    children: [
      {
        index: true,
        element: <Home />,
        loader: homeLoader,
      },
    ],
  },
]);
```

Comment: This method looks more leaner than the wrapper way, I wonder if there's a performance or other kind of possible problems compared to wrapper way. I also wonder that if we could solve this using "useFetcher" hook of react-router-dom to call action method and the use the actionData and dispatch. But could possibly end up writing more code.

Comment: @M.ÇağlarTUFAN No issues I can think of. Sure, using the newer Data hooks and handling it in the component code is an alternative I think could work. At this point you are really just back in the regular component code where you have access to `useDispatch` and can call `dispatch` locally in any function in the component.

Comment: According to [the docs](https://redux.js.org/faq/store-setup#store-setup) this is not a recommended pattern.
```Similarly, while you can reference your store instance by importing it directly, this is not a recommended pattern in Redux. If you create a store instance and export it from a module, it will become a singleton. This means it will be harder to isolate a Redux app as a component of a larger app, if this is ever necessary, or to enable server rendering, because on the server you want to create separate store instances for every request.```

Comment: @IngóVals Thanks for the feedback. "not recommended" is a suggestion. As long as you don't need SSR or any of the other edge/use cases mentioned then using the singleton is not generally a problem or issue.